# How to generalize a function over two types with similar fields in different positions?

Tags: rust

I have a function `algo` which works with a type `S1`, I also have
a type `S2` which contains all of the fields of `S1` plus some additional ones.

How should I modify `algo` to also accept `S2` as input without
creating a temporary variable with type `S1` and data from `S2`?

```
struct Moo1 {
    f1: String,
    f2: i32,
}

struct Moo2 {
    f1: String,
    f2: i32,
    other_fields: f32,
}

struct S1 {
    x: i32,
    v: Vec<Moo1>,
}

struct S2 {
    x: i32,
    v: Vec<Moo2>,
}

//before fn algo(s: &S1)
fn algo<???>(???) {
    //work with x and v (only with f1 and f2)
}
```

**Where I'm stuck**

Let's assume `algo` has this implementation (my real application has another implementation):

```
fn algo(s: &S1) {
    println!("s.x: {}", s.x);
    for y in &s.v {
        println!("{} {}", y.f1, y.f2);
    }
}
```

To access the field in `Moo1` and `Moo2` I introduce `trait AsMoo`, and to access `x` field and `v` I introduce `trait AsS`:

```
trait AsMoo {
    fn f1(&self) -> &str;
    fn f2(&self) -> i32;
}

trait AsS {
    fn x(&self) -> i32;
    //    fn v(&self) -> ???;
}

fn algo<S: AsS>(s: &AsS) {
    println!("s.x: {}", s.x());
}
```

I'm stuck at the implementation of the `AsS::v` method. I do not allocate memory to use my `algo`, but I need a `Vec<&AsMoo>` in some way.

Maybe I need to return some kind of `Iterator<&AsMoo>`, but have no idea how to do it and that looks complex for this problem.

Maybe I should use macros instead?

Comment: Are you aware of [Generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.11.0/book/generics.html)? Their very purpose is to generalize!

Comment: @MatthieuM. It is not so simple, to access field I need trait, but `Vec` require known size, and do not want allocate in heap vector of traits.

Comment: Ah! So you did try something. In this case, could you edit in what trait definition you attempted to use, and what you find unsatisfactory with it? This way we can improve it to make it fit your wishes :)

Comment: You can replace f1 and f2 from Moo2 with a Moo1, and impl Deref<Target=Moo1> for Moo2

Comment: @MatthieuM. I update my question

Comment: @GrégoryOBANOS How this helps with `Vec` of `Moo*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any problem in computer science can be solved by adding another layer of indirection; at the exception of having too many such layers, of course.

Therefore, you are correct that you miss a `S` trait to generalize `S1` and `S2`. In `S`, you can use a feature called *associated type*:

```
trait Moo {
    fn f1(&self) -> &str;
    fn f2(&self) -> i32;
}

trait S {
    type Mooer: Moo;
    fn x(&self) -> i32;
    fn v(&self) -> &[Self::Mooer];
}
```

The bit `type Mooer: Moo;` says: I don't quite know what the exact type `Mooer` will end up being, but it'll implement the `Moo` trait.

This lets you write:

```
impl S for S1 {
    type Mooer = Moo1;
    fn x(&self) -> i32 { self.x }
    fn v(&self) -> &[Self::Mooer] { &self.v }
}

impl S for S2 {
    type Mooer = Moo2;
    fn x(&self) -> i32 { self.x }
    fn v(&self) -> &[Self::Mooer] { &self.v }
}

fn algo<T: S>(s: &T) {
    println!("s.x: {}", s.x());
    for y in s.v() {
        println!("{} {}", y.f1(), y.f2());
    }
}
```

And your generic `algo` knows that whatever type `Mooer` ends up being, it conforms to the `Moo` trait so the interface of `Moo` is available.